# XMLHttpRequest breaks on GET parameters

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get the DOM of a certain page.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open( 'GET', '/sport-hobby-kultura?adListing-visualPaginator-page=2&adListing-url=sport-hobby-kultura&do=adListing-visualPaginator-showPage', true );
// set responseType document to return DOM
req.responseType = 'document' || '';
// set X-Requested-With header to check that is ajax request
req.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
req.send();
```

This returns NULL. Notice the parameters in the URL of the request. When I try to remove them, the request works perfectly (e.g. below):

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open( 'GET', '/sport-hobby-kultura', true );
// set responseType document to return DOM
req.responseType = 'document' || '';
// set X-Requested-With header to check that is ajax request
req.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
req.send();
```

Does anyone have an idea why this works only without the GET params? The page works fine when I access it via browser or API tester.

Comment: We can't really troubleshoot this. Also, my first suggestion would be to use asynchronous `fetch()` instead.

Comment: I would recommend to try this without the "/" in the path. This is the only thing I see not quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.responseType = 'document' || '';` will always equal `"document"`

If the `responseType` is not actually a `"document"`, you **will** get a `null` response.

Try removing the `responseType` and see what is returned or replace it with the correct type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the backend script was only returning a snippet of the page to redraw, I had to redirect the whole page so that the request would return the whole DOM.